# MUI DarkTheme not working in DateRangePicker and datetime-local TextField

Tags: material-ui, react-tsx, darkmode

I encounter some problems with DatePicker and MUI dark mode whereas everyhting works well everywhere else.

**1. For TextField with type="datetime-local"**
I cannot find how to have a white color for the icon
[image: TextField]

```
     <TextField
                  autoComplete="off"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="enddate"
                  variant="outlined"
                  label={'label'}
                  value={formState.enddate}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange('enddate', e)}
                  className={classes.input}
                  type="datetime-local"
                />
```

`sx` props don't work with Typescript `Property 'sx' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & OutlinedTextFieldProps'`

I have other TextField and they work well with the following code

[image]

```
    <TextField
              autoComplete="off"
              error={formState.borrower_start.length === 0}
              required
              fullWidth
              id="borrower_start"
              variant="outlined"
              label="Comentaire"
              value={formState.borrower_start}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange('borrower_start', e)}
              className={classes.input}
              InputProps={{
                endAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <PermIdentityOutlinedIcon />
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
            />
```

How do you think I can handle that AND the fact that the calendar popup is also white, not the expected grey
[image]

**2. For DateRangePicker**
The same issue occurs with [DateRangePicker component from MUI](https://mui.com/api/date-range-picker/)

```
<DateRangePicker
      PopperProps={{ container: document.body }}
      open={pickerOpen}
      disabled={props.disabled}
      startText={props.startText ?? 'Du'}
      endText={props.startText ?? 'Au'}
      disableFuture={props.disableFuture}
      inputFormat={'dd/MM/yyyy'}
      value={internalDateRange}
      onChange={handleDateRangeChange}
      onOpen={onOpen}
      onClose={onClose}
      onError={onError}
      renderInput={renderInput}
      disableCloseOnSelect={false}
    />
```

[image]

I have added `<CssBaseline />` to my App.tsx but nothing seems to work.

I have spent hours trying to find how to solve it through various other questions but nothing is working.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You most likely need to override  the component's css in your theme provider. There is an [example here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/393#issuecomment-591747961)

Answer (score 2):

This is built-in browser component. You need to tell browser that you use dark theme. In MUI you can do that by passing `enableColorScheme` to `CssBaseline` component:

```
<CssBaseline enableColorScheme />
```

---

You can also do that by use css property `color-scheme: dark`. If you want to apply this for whole page then add this property to `:root`. Is it also possible by adding meta tag to head of html:

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark">
```

More about this here:

https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/#aa-handling-user-agent-styles

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme